# Node.JS - Deal with DNS packet

Tags: node.js, dns, network-programming, buffer, protocols

I want read DNS packet catch by UDP server event on.message

How can I read fix size data

packet data manage like
I want read all field of DNS packet by separately by size.

--Read nodejs buffer object bit by bit. (specific size of bit)

[image]

```
var s = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
s.bind(53, function() {

});
s.on('message',function(msg,rinfo){
    console.log("Length = "+msg.length);
    console.log(msg.toString('binary'));
    console.log(msg);
    console.log("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
});
```

how can achieve every field data?
with buffer of on.message param.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please check https://www.npmjs.org/package/native-dns-packet

It provides exactly what you need:

```
Packet.parse(buffer) returns an instance of Packet
Packet.write(buffer, packet) writes the given packet into the buffer, truncating where appropriate
```